# Delimit enum for one class

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I create an enum in all of my UserControls with the actions which are usable for this object which is showed on this UC. For example:

```
private enum ControlActions
  {
     New,
     Edit,
     Delete
  }
```

Almost in every UserControl the actions are the same, so I wanted to make an global enum. But the problem is that there are some UserControls that do not have all of this actions for that object (Sometimes only one, sometimes two). So my question is, is there a way to create a gloabl enum but delimit it?

For example: 
In UserControl1 the actions New and Edit 
In UserControl2 the action Delete
In UserControl3 the actions New, Edit and Delete

Comment: I think you're talking about a `Flags` enum but I don't really understand the question fully.

Comment: Nothing at compile-time. You can create an enum for every control representing the possible values for that control. Or alternativly implement some runtime-validation.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thank for that answer. Too bad that this isn't possible with the enum. I think the runtime-validation would be an overkill for my case. so I'll create multiple enums with the possible compositions of my actions.

Comment: I would have thought a list t of actions or whatever you want to call them. Or maybe a LIst of a viewmodel has CommandName and ICommand

Comment: Give your UserControls some means of reporting which "commands" they support: A virtual method in a common base class, or an interface they all implement. Or give each one an ICommand property for each "command", and write a dummy ICommand implementation which always returns false for `CanExecute()`. You could combine that with the common base class idea, making the ICommand properties virtual.

Comment: What would you hope to gain? In C# that would seem to require some type of enum inheritance, in which case you have different types anyway, or else the compiler couldn't enforce restrictions. How do you envision this working?

Answer (score -2):

You may not be able to solve this in the enum itself, but you could write an extension method that determines whether the action is allowed for a certain control.

```
public enum ControlActions
{
    New,
    Edit,
    Delete
}

public static class ControlActionsExtender
{
    public static bool IsActionAllowed(this ControlActions controlAction, Type controlType)
    {
        switch (controlAction)
        {
            case ControlActions.New:
                return controlType == typeof(UserControlA) || controlType == typeof(UserControlB) || controlType == typeof(UserControlC);
            case ControlActions.Edit:
                return controlType == typeof(UserControlA);
            case ControlActions.Delete:
                return controlType == typeof(UserControlA) || controlType == typeof(UserControlC);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your user control, you could determine whether an action is allowed by calling:

```
// See if we are allowed to create a new item from this control
ControlActions.New.IsAllowed(this.GetType());
```

Comment: Thank you for this interesting answer. The problem is that I have more than 20 UserControls so this method would be extremly big an maybe slowly.

Comment: @Presi I do not think that this is really slow and you could check it if it's slow. The problem is that you are not willing to write out 20 * 3 `controlType == typeof(UserControl...)`. That's called laziness, but need some kind of a permission system/handler and this one looks like the simplest one.

Comment: @Hille It's not about laziness, cause I know the Win-function Ctrl+C an Ctrl+V. I thougt it wouldn't be very efficient to check through all userControls. But I think I will try it like this, if you think it isn't slow. I'll see :)

Comment: @Presi it depends on the system you are trying to run the application. It's surely a few more milliseconds of work on each validation of an enum value, but a few other things were to make own UserControl subclass with a `Validate(enum)` but that would be much more work.

Comment: I understand this might not be the most beautiful and perfect solution you've ever seen, but I don't really understand where the downvotes are coming from.